# Python Requests: Success/Error Not Called

Tags: python, python-requests

Trying to use python requests. I'm getting a {"code":141,"error":"success/error was not called"} error when I try to save the response I receive from the url into a variable and then post it back to a different url. Any ideas how I can fix this?

```
payload = { "email" : "jade@gmail.com", "github" : "https://github.com/"}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', "Accept": 'application/json'}
r = requests.post("http://challenge.code2040.org/r", json = payload, headers = headers)

#Store the token into a variable
token = r.text

payload = { "token" : token}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', "Accept": 'application/json'}
r = requests.post("http://challenge.code2040.org/api/getstring", json = payload, headers = headers)

print r.text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the actual tokens you get back:

Based on the instructions from the main page:

```
================================
Stage I: Reverse a string
================================

Once you’re registered, it’s time to get started on the challenges.

The first one is straightforward. You’re going to reverse a string.

That is, if the API says “cupcake,” you’re going to send back “ekacpuc.”

POST a JSON dictionary with the key token and your previous token value to this endpoint:

http://challenge.code2040.org/api/getstring

The getstring endpoint will return a string that your code should then reverse, as in the example above.

Once that string is reversed, send it back to us. POST some JSON to:

http://challenge.code2040.org/api/validatestring

Use the key token for your token.
Use the key string for your reversed string.
```

Part 1 get out token:

```
payload = { "email" : "jade@gmail.com", "github" : "https://github.com/"}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', "Accept": 'application/json'}
r = requests.post("http://challenge.code2040.org/api/register", json = payload, headers = headers)

#Store the token into a variable
token = r.json()  # {u'result': u'ZO8FFqVjWp'}
```

part 2 get the string:

```
payload = { "token" :token["result"]}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', "Accept": 'application/json'}
r = requests.post("http://challenge.code2040.org/api/getstring", json = payload, headers = headers)

jsn =  r.json() # {"result":"Wv55g"} # we need to reverse that string
```

The final part is actually reversing the string you get from our last post:

```
payload = {"token" :token["result"], "string" :jsn["result"][::-1]} # jsn["result"][::-1]} reverse the string 
r = requests.post("http://challenge.code2040.org/api/validatestring", json = payload, headers = headers)

print(r.json())

{u'result': u'PASS: stage1. Enrollment record updated!'} # all good!
```

You also had an extra `r` in your address `"http://challenge.code2040.org/r" <- should not be there`